# How can I call a console app requiring a parameter that needs double-quotes from PowerShell script?

Tags: .net, powershell, console-application

How can I construct this call below:

> C:> ExecuteFoo "2012-10-21 00:00:00" "2012-10-21 00:00:00"

from the PowerShell Script below:

```
param(
   [string] $ReportStart = (get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00;00"),
   [string] $ReportEnd = (get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59")
)
# ............ Some stuff here
$Process = [diagnostics.process]::Start("$cmdline", "$ReportStart, $ReportEnd")
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code directly

```
& $cmdline $ReportStart $ReportEnd
```

or if escape needed:

```
& $cmdline "`"$ReportStart`"" "`"$ReportEnd`""
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the quotes using `` `" ``

Comment: hi, in powershell, it's `" not \"